# JSON python get value

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How can I get the price value with the `get()` function instead of using `[]`?

As you can see `availableToBack` and `availableToLay` dictionaries can be empty at one point and I am trying to prevent an error when it happens and return `None`.

```
u'ex':
    {u'availableToBack':
        [
            {u'price': 1.02,
            u'size': 2.15}
        ],
    u'availableToLay': [],
    u'tradedVolume': []
    }
```

The way I get price is:

```
price = ['ex']['availableToBack'][0][price]
```

But in case of availableToLay it would give a key error. I know there is another way which would give None if value does not exist.

```
price = get('ex')...
```

Just can't figure out how construct this complex version of it. Can you hep?

Comment: maybe im missing something, but if you replace `price = ['ex']['availableToBack'][0][price]` with `price=ex.get('availableToBack').get(0).get(price)` this should do what you want

Answer (score 1):

This approach will get you all available prices.

```
ex = {'ex':
        {u'availableToBack':
            [
                {u'price': 1.02,
                 u'size': 2.15}
            ],
        u'availableToLay': [],
        u'tradedVolume': []
        }
    }

for ex_list in ex.get('ex', {}).values():
    if not ex_list:
        continue

    for item in ex_list:
        price = item.get('price')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you could use [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module to convert your json into a python dictionary, you cannot call `ex` dict the way you are doing.

Then, in order not to except `KeyError`, you should use `get()` method that returns `None` (by default) if the key does not exist

Comment: Not quite. If you fail on your first get, and default to `None`, every subsequent call will fail. There needs to be a better check, or even better, just wrap with a try/except indicating that the key could not be found.